# Local import failing with Python 2.7 only

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, python-2.x, importerror

I am running a test suite with tox, and one of my local imports is performing fine in Python 3.7 but failing with Python 2.7.

I get the error:

```
ImportError while importing test module /home/myname/tests/myfolder/test_triad_2020_orgs.py
Traceback:
tests/myfolder/test_triad_2020_orgs.py:5: in <module>
from [testssibbling].myfolder.triad.triad_2020_orgs import Orgs

Import Error: No module named triad.triad_2020_orgs
```

Any ideas on why this could be? The file definitely exists. Is there a problem with the file name for 2.7 conventions?

Comment: Do you have file named ```__init__.py``` in the specified folder?

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you!!

Comment: Nice! So I will explain it as an answer, and you may accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to import python modules in python 3.2 and ealier, there should be a file named `__init__.py` which is responsible to introduce the package as a python package. From python 3.3+ it is implicitly executed.

Based on [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#regular-packages) we have two types of packages: regular package (contain `__init__.py`) and namespace package (not contained). You need to add this file to import the file in python 3.2 and ealier.

You may take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/448279/8961443) to find more information about this file.